# Switching rows with columns to generate a summary report in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have this query that geneartes data in format also shown:

```
SELECT TOP (10)
       { FN CONCAT({ FN CONCAT(dbo.BILL_INFO.BILL_NUMBER, '-')}, REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(RTRIM(dbo.BILL_INFO.PAY_MODE_ID)))
                                                                 + RTRIM(dbo.BILL_INFO.PAY_MODE_ID))} AS Id,
       dbo.BILL_INFO.PAY_MODE_ID,
       dbo.MASTER_PAY_MODE.NAME AS PAY_MODE
FROM dbo.BILL_INFO
    INNER JOIN dbo.MASTER_PAY_MODE
        ON dbo.BILL_INFO.PAY_MODE_ID = dbo.MASTER_PAY_MODE.ID
ORDER BY dbo.BILL_INFO.BILL_DATE DESC;
```

[image: Result of query]

I need to transpose the result to this format:

[image: Required result]

I can do this using excel and a pivot but is there a way using SQL query?

**Sample Data**

```
Id                |BILL_DATE              |PAY_MODE
0000056-1002-18-10|2018-11-26 14:03:03.553|Bank Transfer
0001199-1002-18-05|2018-11-26 13:58:25.763|Credit Card
0000162-1030-18-05|2018-11-26 13:55:40.590|Credit Card
0001198-1002-18-05|2018-11-26 13:49:39.013|Credit Card
0001859-1030-18-04|2018-11-26 13:44:23.333|Free
0004443-1002-18-03|2018-11-26 13:42:27.550|Debit
0001532-1031-18-03|2018-11-26 13:36:23.010|Debit
0001916-1002-18-04|2018-11-26 13:33:23.157|Free
0001915-1002-18-04|2018-11-26 13:32:45.653|Free
0001914-1002-18-04|2018-11-26 13:30:35.580|Free
0004442-1002-18-03|2018-11-26 13:24:11.730|Debit
0004441-1002-18-03|2018-11-26 13:22:35.020|Debit
0004440-1002-18-03|2018-11-26 13:12:01.920|Debit
0004439-1002-18-03|2018-11-26 13:10:06.483|Debit
0001197-1002-18-05|2018-11-26 13:07:19.673|Credit Card
0001196-1002-18-05|2018-11-26 13:02:31.527|Credit Card
0004438-1002-18-03|2018-11-26 13:00:01.000|Debit
0001003-1030-18-03|2018-11-26 12:57:42.630|Debit
0001531-1031-18-03|2018-11-26 12:56:33.210|Debit
0001913-1002-18-04|2018-11-26 12:54:41.077|Free
```

**Update**
I have taken the solution provided by @[Tim Biegeleisen] as follows:

```
SELECT
     MONTH(bi.BILL_DATE) AS [Month],
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Cheque' THEN bi.PAY_MODE_ID END) AS Cheque,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Cash'   THEN bi.PAY_MODE_ID END) AS Cash,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Bank Transfer' THEN bi.PAY_MODE_ID END) AS [Bank Transfer],
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Credit Card' THEN bi.PAY_MODE_ID END) AS [Credit Card],
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Debit' THEN bi.PAY_MODE_ID END) AS Debit,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Free' THEN bi.PAY_MODE_ID END) AS Free
FROM dbo.BILL_INFO bi
INNER JOIN dbo.MASTER_PAY_MODE m
    ON bi.PAY_MODE_ID = m.ID
    WHERE YEAR(bi.BILL_DATE) = 2018
GROUP BY
     MONTH(bi.BILL_DATE) ORDER BY  MONTH(bi.BILL_DATE)
```

[image: Second result]

Comment: Please provide sample data for both tables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have placed a sample data extract that I'd like to transpose

Comment: The data doesn't make much sense.  The rows are dates/month, the columns are the pay mode, but what are the values?  Which column gives the values?

Comment: Sorry. I want to count the number of times each payment mode was used per month

Comment: Check my updated answer.  For the next time you post here, _don't_ include images.  Just show sample data and the expected output, as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do so via a pivot query, perhaps something alone these lines:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(bi.BILL_DATE) + '-' + MONTH(bi.BILL_DATE) AS Date,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Cheque' THEN 1 END) AS Cheque,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Cash'   THEN 1 END) AS Cash,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Bank Transfer' THEN 1 END) AS [Bank Transfer],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Credit Card' THEN 1 END) AS [Credit Card],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Debit' THEN 1 END) AS Debit,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN m.NAME = 'Free' THEN 1 END) AS Free
FROM dbo.BILL_INFO bi
INNER JOIN dbo.MASTER_PAY_MODE m
    ON bi.PAY_MODE_ID = m.ID
GROUP BY
    YEAR(bi.BILL_DATE) + '-' + MONTH(bi.BILL_DATE);
```

Note that I am grouping the date column by month *and* year, because a given month appearing in the `BILL_INFO` table could belong to more than one year, in general.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an image. The result that is being produced is not as expected. I have fixed the year to 2018 and only group by month as the original query was not printing Date column correctly.

Comment: SUM instead of MAX?

Comment: I reached COUNT just as you also edited. Problem solved.